# Identifying when finite-size scaling effects dominate a power law distribution

Tags: distributions, fitting, power-law

Suppose we sample from a distribution of the random variable $x$ that is basically a power law (with exponent $\alpha$) for values of $x$ close to some minimum $x_{\min}$, but differs significantly from that power law once $x$ gets close to some value $x_c$ smaller than the maximum value $x_{\max}$ that $x$ can take. More formally, we have

$p(x) \sim L(x/x_c) x^{-\alpha} \text{ for } x_{\min} \leq x \leq x_{\max}$

where $L(x/x_c)$ is an *unknown* slow-varying function such that $L(x/x_c) \rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow x_{\min}$ for some $x_c$ such that $x_{\min} << x_c << x_{\max}$.

What are good ways of finding the value of $x_c$?

(If it makes a difference, I’m particularly interested in the case where the random variable is discrete. To be concrete, I am studying a physics model where, if the model size were infinite, the size $x$ of certain events it generates, which can only be a positive integer, would follow a perfect power law distribution, but in simulations the model has to be a finite size, so larger event sizes diverge quite a bit from this ideal power law.)